# How to sum non-consecutive values when using group by in MySQL

Tags: mysql, group-by, subquery

I have a data set representing alarms' state at a given timestamp (every 15 minutes). When the value is 1 the alarm is `ON`, 0 when `OFF`. I am trying to count the number of times the alarm has been triggered per hour (non-consecutive 1).

I took a look at [Count max number of consecutive occurrences of a value in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46426820/count-max-number-of-consecutive-occurrences-of-a-value-in-sql-server) but couldn't manage to adapt the answer.

Basically the data set for one alarm looks like this:

```
| id |   value  |    registered_at    |   
| -- | ---------|---------------------|
|  1 |     1    | 2012-07-15  06:00   |
|  2 |     0    | 2012-07-15  06:15   |
|  3 |     1    | 2012-07-15  06:30   |
|  4 |     0    | 2012-07-15  06:45   |
|  5 |     1    | 2012-07-15  07:00   |
|  6 |     1    | 2012-07-15  07:15   |
|  7 |     1    | 2012-07-15  07:30   |
|  8 |     0    | 2012-07-15  07:45   |
|  8 |     0    | 2012-07-15  08:00   |
```

The results I am looking for is the following

```
|   registered_at    | alarm_triggered | 
|--------------------|-----------------|
|   2012-07-15  06   |        2        |
|   2012-07-15  07   |        1        |
|   2012-07-15  08   |        0        |
```

To create groups I use `EXTRACT(DAY_HOUR from registered_at)`.
Can you help me create the query?

(First time poster on SO, any feedback about the form of this post would be greatly appreciated as well)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use LAG() window function to check the value of `value` of the previous row and if it is different and the current row is `1` then sum:

```
SELECT registered_at, 
       SUM(value * flag) alarm_triggered 
FROM (
  SELECT value,
         DATE_FORMAT(registered_at, '%Y-%m-%d %H') registered_at, 
         value <> LAG(value, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY DATE_FORMAT(registered_at, '%m-%d-%Y %H') ORDER BY registered_at) flag
  FROM tablename
) t
GROUP BY registered_at
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1df2d1ddea304970224cdfff4dfd4ac9).
Results:

| registered_at | alarm_triggered |
| --- | --- |
| 2012-07-15 06 | 2 |
| 2012-07-15 07 | 1 |
| 2012-07-15 08 | 0 |

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, awesome, thanks! The other answers were simple sum that did not cover my initial question.

Comment: While it seems to perfectly work for group per hour, I have weird results with days. I adapted it by replacing DATE_FORMAT(registered_at, '%m-%d-%Y %H') with DATE_FORMAT(registered_at, '%m-%d-%Y')

Comment: @Tcheetox I don't have your actual data. For the sample data in your question the result is this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bb61d5e7ff94eaf1d7d50631e0afb250

Comment: Please disregard, I did crap on my side. The solution was right there :)

Answer (score 0):

I assume the registered_at field is datetime so you need to use datetime function.

here is a query  for this:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(registered_at, "%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00") AS registered_at, SUM(VALUE) AS alarm_triggered 
FROM ALARMS
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(registered_at, "%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00")
```

and sqlfiddle to see example:

[example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/df5a59/3)

Answer (score 0):

If you need only notified days

```
select count(value), date_format(registered_at, '%m-%d-%Y %H') as c_at
from notifications
where value = 1
group by date_format(registered_at, '%m-%d-%Y %H');
```

Or all days

```
select sum(value), date_format(registered_at, '%m-%d-%Y %H') as c_at
from notifications
group by date_format(registered_at, '%m-%d-%Y %H');
```

Try this!

Answer (score 0):

You can select it like this:

```
SELECT CONCAT(YEAR(registered_at), '-', MONTH(registered_at), '-', DAYOFMONTH(registered_at), ' ' HOUR(registered_at)), count(*)
FROM alarms
WHERE value = 1
GROUP BY YEAR(registered_at), MONT(registered_at), DAYOFMONTH(registered_at), HOUR(registered_at);
```

## Explanation

First, we find the records whose value is 1, then group them by year, month, day of month and hour and finally we find out their count.